# In Recycler View I want to remove specific index items but index gets change after removing first item and the result gets change

Tags: android

I have ArrayList like {A B C D E f} and I want to remove index by 1,3,5 positions respectively,
After removing an item from 1 position, then ArrayList look like { A C D E F}.
Then after if I remove an item from the 3rd position, it removes E instead of D so I do not get the required result.

I have tried all methods of notify...();

```
public class branchadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<branchadapter.MyViewHolder>  {
    public static ArrayList<branchdata> ndata;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
        private final Context context;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            context = itemView.getContext();
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.t2);
        }
    }
    public branchadapter(ArrayList<branchdata> list) {
        ndata = list;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from((viewGroup.getContext())).inflate(R.layout.branchcard, viewGroup, false);
        MyViewHolder evh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return evh;
    }
    @Override

    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {
        branchdata mlist = ndata.get(i);
        myViewHolder.textView.setText(mlist.getText());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ndata.size();
    }

    public void removeAt(int position) {

                    ndata.remove(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: While deleting data from `ndata` delete the same from your orginal list to sync the positions

Comment: You don't need to notify() adapter, because notify method does refresh your ArrayList.

Comment: A really simple (albeit hacky) way to do this would be to decrement all your indexes by 1 each time you remove an item from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have different element in your list,

you can use `list.remove(element)` instead of `list.remove(position)`

```
list = arrayListOf("a", "b", "c")
list.remove("b")
```

Comment: It is not taking string in place of Integer.

Comment: did you try and get errors ? it does not require string or integer, it can be any object you want

Answer (score 0):

Use some `id` such as `id of the item` or `item itself` for deletion rather than the position.

Your remove method should take an item as an argument and look for its position in the current list and then remove it.

```
public void removeAt(Item item) {
    int itemPosition = nData.indexOf(item);
    ndata.remove(itemPosition);
}
```

Also, make sure to notify adapter that **item at itemPosition** has been removed.